# API designing - best practice and how to support multiple versions

Tags: api, architecture

What is the best way to design the API's which supports multiple versions. How do I ensure that even if the schema of my data changes(minor changes), the consumers of my api's are not affected? Any reference architecture, guidelines is really helpful.

Comment: Which language/platform?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Mark Nottingham has a good blog post on how to version Web (REST) APIs

http://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/10/25/web_api_versioning_smackdown

Also about API versioning in general:

http://theamiableapi.com/2011/10/18/api-design-best-practice-plan-for-evolution/

Comment: Incredibly valuable references . Thanks.